# Error while trying to run PHP from the command line

Tags: php, cmd

I am using Windows 7 x64 and trying to run a small PHP program from the command line. I have php placed in `C:/php` and my program is at: `C:/schoolproject/launch.php`

So I run: `C:/php/php.exe -f "C:/schoolproject/launch.php"`

Then I get an erorr: `PHP.EXE is not a valid Win32 Application`

I know there are lots of documented cases of this but I haven't so far found a succesfull fix for this and it is really bugging me as I need it to work. I have re-installed Windows 7 to no avail.

Thank you

Comment: Which file you downloaded to install php?

Comment: I can't remember the actual file although I have had this working perfectly previously, I must have changed something but can't work out what. Thank you.

Comment: You could always reinstall PHP, and check if that solves the problem.

Comment: The thing is I never "installed it" so to say, I just placed the downloaded folder in C:/ and referenced it and it worked. I really need this to work soon (as in within an hour) as I have a project needing handed in tomorrow morning so I might end up booting Linux.

Thanks for all the help everyone.

Comment: If you need a quick solve, download this: [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) it will install PHP and a web server ready to function.

Comment: Thanks Ricardo, this needs to be run from the command line though (ie Cmd.exe) as I need to take it to school and I don't fancy convincing my comp. sci. teacher to let me install a WAMP stack like the one mentioned on top of Windows XP.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24792/discussion-between-joshua-dempsey-and-ricardo-ortega-magana)